# create custon url with directory names but not using them

Tags: php, url

I am using `www.xyz.com/bhb/microsite.php`

i want this to looks like `www.xyz.com/bhb/2015/manufacturing/abcname/microsite.php.`

but the file path must be same. In actual this directories not exist and don't want to create this directories. Just want to add this name in URL

Comment: Which server are you using, Apache or Nginx? I'll bet on Apache, which means you should look into htaccess rewrite rules: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 1):

this is possible with .htaccess file create in and write rule for this

Comment: can i get some example for this rule?

Comment: watch this link total solution of your problem[http://viralpatel.net/blogs/21-very-useful-htaccess-tips-tricks/]

Comment: i used somthing lik this

RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^bhb/manufacturing/2015/xyzname/?$    microsite.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "microsite"